# pictureBoxes disappear after moving one on the panel

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want to move an already placed `pictureBox` in a `panel` to another location in the `panel`. The thing is, let's say I place 3 `pictureBox`es into the `panel` and I want to move one of them, the selected one moves successfully but the others just disappear. I also have a `List` of type `PictureBox`, in which I store the `pictureBox`es, and the count stays the same of course, after they disappear visually. Here is my code.

```
    namespace DragDrop
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Point> points;
    List<PictureBox> pics;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializePoints();
        pics = new List<PictureBox>();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(pictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void panel1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }

    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point cursor = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        Point draw = new Point();

        foreach (Point p in points)
        {
            if (cursor.X > p.X && cursor.Y > p.Y)
            {
                draw = p;
            }
        }

        if (e.AllowedEffect == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            foreach (Point p in points)
            {
                foreach (PictureBox pbb in pics)
                {
                    if (pbb.Location == p)
                    {
                        pbb.Parent = this;
                        pbb.Location = draw;
                        Console.WriteLine(pics.Count());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Height = panel1.Height / 3;
            pb.Width = panel1.Width / 4;
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Mouse_Down);
            pb.Parent = this;
            pics.Add(pb);
            this.Controls.Add(pb);

            pb.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
            pb.BringToFront();
            pb.Location = draw;
        }
    }

    private void Mouse_Down(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).DoDragDrop(((PictureBox)sender).Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void InitializePoints()
    {
        points = new List<Point>();

        int pleft = panel1.Left;
        int ptop = panel1.Top;
        int cellwidth = panel1.Width / 4;
        int cellheigth = panel1.Height / 3;

        //First row
        points.Add(new Point(pleft, ptop));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + cellwidth, ptop));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + 2 * cellwidth, ptop));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + 3 * cellwidth, ptop));

        //Second row
        points.Add(new Point(pleft, ptop + cellheigth));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + cellwidth, ptop + cellheigth));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + 2 * cellwidth, ptop + cellheigth));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + 3 * cellwidth, ptop + cellheigth));

        //Third row
        points.Add(new Point(pleft, ptop + 2 * cellheigth));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + cellwidth, ptop + 2 * cellheigth));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + 2 * cellwidth, ptop + 2 * cellheigth));
        points.Add(new Point(pleft + 3 * cellwidth, ptop + 2 * cellheigth));
    }
}
}
```

Screenshots:
Here I have placed 3 `picturebox`es and want to move the circled one.
[image]
And here I moved it and the rest disappeared.
[image]

Comment: The picture box locations will be relative to the panel they are housed within, can you confirm that the points you create are correct? I'm thinking you might need to call `panel.PointToClient`.

Comment: You keep asking this question with *insufficient* documentation.  A screenshot is not enough for anybody to guess what is wrong with your code.  This is not youtube.com, post *complete* code instead of //... comments.

Comment: @HansPassant Put in the complete code.

Comment: Very hard to see what the code tries to accomplish.  It is certainly wrong, you can't just arbitrary change the Parent and Location property of all the picture boxes.  You'll end up stacking them all on top of each other or putting them *behind* the panel.  Start fixing this by passing the picture box instead of the image in the DoDragDrop call so you always know which one is getting dragged.  And get rid of the panel so you don't fight the Parent property.

Comment: If the panel is the parent of your pixtureboxes then you points should be relative to the panel .note that you included the panel left and top in your calculations of points which is not correct if the panel is the parent.

Comment: Please do not edit away your question.  I rolled it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code might be the cause:

```
foreach (Point p in points)
{
    foreach (PictureBox pbb in pics)
    {
        if (pbb.Location == p)
        {
            pbb.Parent = this;
            pbb.Location = draw;
            Console.WriteLine(pics.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding, this code will check through all picture box whether it is located in one of the location registered in `points`. Since all picture box is located at one of the location registered in `points`, in the end all three picture box will be located at the same location which is `draw`.

Comment: glad to be of some help